# CMake add library as dependency by condition

Tags: cmake

I have CMake project with two targets:

1. `add_custom_target (CT)` - generates "cpp headers" or "cpp headers + cpp sources". Whether only headers or also sources are generated is determined at build time (when `CT` is built).
2. `add_library (AL)` - generates some library

`AL` depends on `CT`

Is it possible to compile the sources generated by `CT` into a library (necessary!!!) and add this library as dependency for `AL`?

Comment: So you want CT to generate some sources, then build a library L out of those sources, and then link that into AL?

Comment: Yes. But sometime CT produces only headers and I do not need this library (In this case I only need that AL depends on CT). But if cpp sources were produced I want to compile them into the library and add it as dependency to AL.

Comment: When is it known whether CT will produce sources or not? At CMake time, or at build time?

Comment: I would like this at build time but if it it is not possible I'll try to generate sources at CMake time.

Comment: That's not quite what I asked. The sources can be generated at build time. But is it known at CMake time whether/which sources will be generated?

Comment: If you ask about type, then yes: *.h and *.cpp. If you ask whether *.cpp sources will be generated at CMake time, then no

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm afraid the answer is "no." CMake does not really support sources which are not known when CMake itself is running. If you can split `CT` into a part which determines what sources there will be (Part A), and a part which actually generates the sources (Part B), you can run Part A at CMake time and use the information to construct the library and `AL`, with Part B then replacing `CT` and happening at build time.